# Missing url parameters values after running powershell script as scheduled task

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a Powershell script that gets the name of a computer as string and the processes running on it as json array, creates parameters from the variables, then makes a web request to a url and has 2 parameters sent through the POST method as shown below:

```
$comp_id = (Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem) | Select-Object  csname | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | out-string
$processes = get-process | Where-Object {$_.StartTime -ne $null -and $_.MainWindowTitle.Length -gt 10}  | Select-Object id,description,FileVersion,mainWindowTitle,startTime| ConvertTo-Json

# create parameters from variables
$param1= @{id=$comp_id}
$param2 = @{data=$processes} #the variable $process is a JSON array string 
$bothParams = $param1+$param2

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://my.webserver.comp:8080/galileo/peeker -Method POST-Body $bothParams
```

Everything is OK when I run the script directly i.e both parameter values are accesible from a servlet.

I want to run this script as a scheduled task so I've created a batch script file that calls the powershell script. The problem is that **when the script runs as a scheduled task, the second parameter,supposed to be a JSON array string, is empty.** What could be the problem?

My batch script has the following 2 lines:

```
 @echo OFF
# used batch script tag(%~dpn0) to get path (p) and file name similar to this file
Powershell.exe -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
```

Comment: I guess it's a path issue; share your batch script;

Comment: How do you assign anything to `$comp_id` and `$processes`?

Comment: Hi. I edited the question to include the call made from the batch file and how `$comp_id` and `$process` get their values. Hope its more clear now..

Comment: Which account Task Scheduler is using to run the script?

Comment: Iam running the script using normal user account, a've set to it run using highest priviledges and Powershell is set to 'unrestricted' mode for all scripts.

Comment: If it may help..here's how the url looks like on the server: `http://my.webserver.com:8080/galileo/peeker?id=comp_id_value&data=` as you can see the data parameter is empty

Comment: `$comp_id = (Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem) | Select-Object  csname | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | out-string` - that's a very tortured way of writing `$comp_id = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).CSName`. No need for formatting or `Out-String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run PowerShell scripts directly from Task Scheduler so you don't need the batch script. As for why JSON string ends up empty, the most likely reason is that `Where-Object` doesn't capture anything.

Adding some basic debug logging to your script could help you get some idea about what's going on. Example:

```
$logFile = "script.log"

$env:USERNAME | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
Get-Process | Select-Object Id, Description, FileVersion, MainWindowTitle, StartTime `
    | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
```

Comment: Hi Allexander, thanks for the logging tip. my `get-process` line works fine when I ran it directly but has issues when run as a scheduled task. I'll try to log output to file as you've suggested and see what I get.